# Replacing values of a two dimensional array

Tags: java

I have a given two dimensional array of doubles, called `imgMatrix` and I'm trying to make a new two dimensional array of integers either 1 or 0, depending on the values of the doubles in `imgMatrix` (value <= 0.5 makes a 0 in the new array; value > 0.5 makes a 1 in the new array).

Here's the code I have so far:

```
int[][] newMatrix = new int[imgMatrix.length][];
for (a=0; a <= imgMatrix.length; a++) {
    for (b=0; b <= imgMatrix[a].length; b++) {
        for (c=0; c <= imgMatrix[a].length; c++) {
            if (imgMatrix[a][c] <= 0) {
                newMatrix[a][c] = 0;
            }
            else {
                newMatrix[a][c] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously something is wrong. Can anybody help me correct this?

Comment: You're going to run off the end of your arrays, use `< length` not `<= length`.

Comment: You say 'obviously'... but what do you perceive being wrong? Be sure to tell us what outputs you're getting, and what you EXPECT to get for a given input!

Comment: I can see an obvious error, but I don't know if it is related to the obvious problem you are talking about.  (Actually, I can see a few obvious errors ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do following changes into your code,

```
int[][] newMatrix = new int[imgMatrix.length][];
    for (int a=0; a < imgMatrix.length; a++) { // remove = from older code

        newMatrix[a] = new int[imgMatrix[a].length];

        for (int b=0; b < imgMatrix[a].length; b++) { // remove = from older code
           //remove : for (c=0; c <= imgMatrix[a].length; c++) {
                if (imgMatrix[a][b] <= 0.5) {
                    newMatrix[a][b] = 0;
                }
                else {
                    newMatrix[a][b] = 1;
                }
         // remove :   }
        }
    }
```